# Reactjs - Component as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am rendering different components based on the **URL** using `BrowserRouter` and `Route`. But, There is a lot of markup which is similar while rendering. So, I have created a `Wrapper` which should take components as props and solve this!!

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setActiveTab(this.props.activeTab);
        console.log('Wrapper props: ', this.props)
    }

    render() {
        const OtherComponent = this.props.otherComponent

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col md='8' id='content-block'>
                    <SwitchTab />
                </Col>
                <Col md='4' id='info-block'>
                    <InfoComponent info={this.props.info} {...this.props}/>
                    {
                        this.otherComponent &&
                        <OtherComponent {...this.props}/>
                    }
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}
```

These are some of the Routes:

```
<Route 
    exact 
    path='/r/all/' 
    render={() =>
        <Wrapper 
            setActiveTab={context.toggleTab} 
            activeTab={'3'} 
            info='all'
        />
    }
/>
<Route 
    exact 
    path='/u/:username/' 
    render={(props) => {
        return (
            <Wrapper 
                setActiveTab={context.toggleTab} 
                activeTab={'4'}
                info='user'
                user={props.match.params.username}
                otherComponent={Profile}
                username={props.match.params.username}
            />
            // <Profile username={props.match.params.username} />
        )
    }}
/>
<Route
    exact
    path='/r/:subreddit/'
    render={(props) => {
        return (
            <Wrapper 
                setActiveTab={context.toggleTab} 
                activeTab={'4'} 
                info='subreddit'
                otherComponent={Subreddit}
                subreddit={props.match.params.subreddit}
            />
            // <Subreddit subreddit={props.match.params.subreddit} />
        )
    }}
/>
```

The otherComponent is not getting rendered. I don't know where the problem is. Also if there is any other better method, please do state that.

Comment: is this a typo `this.otherComponent`? shoudn't it be `this.props.otherComponent`?

Comment: Yep `this.props.otherComponent` or `OtherComponent`, both work. I feel silly now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if `this.otherComponent` is truthy before rendering. You just want to check if `OtherComponent` is truthy.

```
{OtherComponent && <OtherComponent {...this.props} />}
```

You could also change `Wrapper` to render `children` if you would prefer.

**Example**

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setActiveTab(this.props.activeTab);
    console.log("Wrapper props: ", this.props);
  }

  render() {
    const { children, ...restProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col md="8" id="content-block">
          <SwitchTab />
        </Col>
        <Col md="4" id="info-block">
          <InfoComponent {...restProps} />
          {children}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

// Usage
<Wrapper>
  <OtherComponent />
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: How would this work if the `OtherComponent` has props?

Comment: @SreekarMouli Do you mean the second example? It works as expected, e.g. `<Wrapper><OtherComponent aProp='foo' anotherProp='bar' /></Wrapper>`

Comment: so `{children}` will render the `OtherComponent` along with its props. Got it! I think its way cleaner to user `{children}`

Answer (score 2):

```
this.otherComponent &&
                    <OtherComponent {...this.props}/>
```

A quick look, `this.otherComponent` is not defined so the component is not getting rendered, should be `this.props.otherComponent`??